# How to rewrite this php more efficiently

Tags: php, if-statement

I need to display manual/automatic transmission vehicle information, and the best I can come up with is the following code. I think its wrong and inefficient, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

```
<?php
if ($obj->AutoTrans == 'S'):
  echo "Automatic";
  if ($obj->ManualTrans == 'O'):
    echo " (Manual Optional)";
  endif;                   
elseif($obj->ManualTrans == 'S'):
  echo "Manual";
  if ($obj->AutoTrans == 'O'):
    echo " (Automatic Optional)";
  endif;     
endif;                  
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is by no means any sort of question. Try again.

Comment: How do you measure `efficiency` saying that "I think its wrong and *inefficient*"

Comment: True, he forgot the question mark, but I don't think it's *that* bad. It's likely he was trying to ask something like: "Is there a cleaner/better/more concise way to write this code?"

Comment: There is too many way to write it, but it works no? If it so what do you expect less line, more compact code, less test... Too many axis of amelioration (only if we consider what we can do would be better...)  Describe your expectation and why you said It's wrong

Comment: Yes, @MarkByers is correct. I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($obj->AutoTrans == 'S')
    echo "Automatic".($this->ManualTrans=='O'?' (Manual Optional)':'');

if ($obj->ManualTrans == 'S')
    echo "Manual".($this->AutoTrans=='O'?' (Automatic Optional)':'');
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inefficient about this method.  You could write it cleaner (in my opinion) by using curly braces instead of using block syntax, though.